# saving bitmap - IO Exception

Tags: android, bitmap, save, sd-card, ioexception

When I save my bitmap, it takes me to IOExeption, why? I dont know:

```
    static Bitmap[] bmp = new Bitmap[4];

public static void save(FileIO files, int location) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() 
                  + File.separator + "test" + File.separator + "mind");
        Log.d("path", f.toString());
        f.createNewFile();
        // write the bytes in file
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        bmp[location].compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
        Log.d("fisnish", "Bitmap saved");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("IO", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Logcat when I save:

```
01-29 00:53:58.020: DEBUG/path(8222): /mnt/sdcard/test/mind
01-29 00:53:58.060: DEBUG/IO(8222): Permission denied
01-29 00:53:58.240: DEBUG/dalvikvm(8222): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 7K, 53% free 2563K/5379K, external 5375K/6713K, paused 178ms
01-29 00:54:02.029: DEBUG/dalvikvm(4723): GC_EXPLICIT freed 7K, 53% free 2643K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 3421ms
```

I have the user permission that I need() But it doesn't work anyway. What's the problem?

Comment: u found any exception with this code.

Comment: Yes, when I try to use bmp[i] it gives me a NullPointerException

Comment: not sure but u have check is your file on your location or not.

Comment: in = new FileInputStream(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator + "numbers" + i);
what is this?

Comment: is ur bitmap here or not can u plz check it manually..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7131/discussion-between-mayur-bhola-and-daniel)

Comment: 01-29 00:22:42.129: D/IO(8025): Permission denied

Comment: show ur logcat here of IOException.

Answer (score 2):

try this scale bitmaps by using canvas.drawBitmap with providing matrix.

```
public static Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int wantedWidth, int wantedHeight) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(wantedWidth, wantedHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    m.setScale((float) wantedWidth / bitmap.getWidth(), (float) wantedHeight / bitmap.getHeight());
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, m, new Paint());

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you including the correct permissions?  You will need the write to external storage permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Edit**

Try placing the file within a directory on the SDCARD, such as:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() 
      + File.separator + "test" + File.Separator + "mind");
```

Comment: Yes I am, now when I checket the stacktrace it stands: "Persission denied". Why?

Comment: Please post your logcat exception.  It will help to figure out the issue

Comment: Also, what is the full path that you are trying to write to?  Does it end up being /sdcard/mind?  I've seen some cases where you may need to write to a folder on the SDCARD rather than the root.

Comment: exception:01-29 00:22:42.129: D/IO(8025): Permission denied

Comment: I have checked the path, the result should work: 01-29 00:19:44.119: D/path(7994): /mnt/sdcard/mind

Comment: The full logcat would be very helpful, if you could post that in your original question.  Also, I've edited my answer, give that a shot.

Comment: Take a look at the following link:  http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/5c310f8b6168497a    It may be that the SDCARD is read only, or if you have it mounted to your computer it could cause some issues.  Good luck

Comment: This gives me real bad resault :(: 01-29 01:16:08.549: INFO/tag(8331): State = removed Not good
01-29 01:16:08.580: INFO/tag(8331): Available= false    Writeable= false    State= removed

Answer (score 1):

Loading sounds like a job for [BitmapFactory.decodeFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String%29).  Also, I would compress directly to your file output stream:

```
public static void save(FileIO files, int location) {
    try {
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "numbers" + location);
        // write the bytes in file
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        bmp[location].compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 40, fo);
        fo.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```